# "Каждый раз(,) перед тем, как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, вставная-конструкция

Конструкция следующая:

> Каждый раз, перед тем как что-то выпить, съесть или просто надкусить,
>   он делал торжественное лицо.

Меня интересует здесь "перед тем как". Теоретически оборот стоит перед той частью, от которой зависит, и запятые вроде как не нужны внутри союза ("перед тем как"). С другой стороны, меня тут смущают однородные присоединения к обороту ("выпить", "съесть"). Не могу объяснить, что кажется неорганичным... наверное, то, что из-за дополнительных запятых не видно чётко, где закрывается оборот. И мне интуитивно хочется поставить запятую после "тем". Как здесь быть с пунктуацией в целом и как "перед тем как" присоединяется к "каждый раз"? Сливается или разделяется запятой?

Comment: Как сделать бежево-охристый фон ?

Comment: @Cloud Это форматирование цитат. Ctrl+Q, или мышкой в меню на кавычки (см. подписи к меню), или просто начните строку с символа > .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Составные подчинительные союзы ввиду того что; вместо того чтобы; в случае если / когда; в то время как; для того чтобы; до того как; мало того что; на случай если; несмотря на то что; оттого что; **перед тем как**; подобно тому как; по мере того как; после того как; потому что; прежде чем; при том что; с тем чтобы; с тех пор как могут целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но могут и расчленяться

Составной подчинительный союз расчленяется и запятая ставится между частями союза, если выполняется хотя бы одно из следующих условий:

1 перед составным союзом имеется **отрицание «не»**: Она любила Ричардсона // Не потому, чтобы прочла, // Не потому, чтоб Грандисона // Она Ловласу предпочла… А. Пушкин, Евгений Онегин.

2 перед составным союзом есть **усилительные, ограничительные и другие частицы, вводные слова, наречия**: Этюд казался ей ничтожным, и написала она его только затем, чтобы иметь лишний предлог сходить к художнику. А. Чехов, Попрыгунья.

3 **первая часть составного союза входит в ряд однородных членов предложения или параллельных конструкций**: Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слез от своего бессилия и растерянности, и от боли за оскорбленную Шурочку, и оттого, что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки кадрили не удавалось вставить ни одного слова. А. Куприн, Поединок.

4 автор желает подчеркнуть, что **на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение**: Мужики тихи, робки и вежливы оттого, что у каждого для весу в кудели по камню… М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша.

В вашем случае, как мне кажется, подходят пункты 2 и 4, можно союз разделять запятой, а можно и не разделять, этому есть примеры в НКРЯ.
Материалы с Грамота.ру.

Comment: Второй не подходит.

Comment: Считаете ли Вы возможным вариант с двумя запятыми: после "каждый раз" и перед "как"? (Я надеюсь, что нет, но решил упомянуть об этом для других участников и посетителей, поскольку Ваш ответ отмечен как принятый.)

Comment: Нет, либо запятая перед составным союзом (каждый раз, ), либо перед «как».

Answer (score 3):

*Каждый раз... он делал торжественное лицо.*

А какой это –  ***каждый***?

И вот здесь требуется **уточнение**: *Каждый раз, (когда именно?) **перед тем как что-то выпить, съесть или просто надкусить,** он делал торжественное лицо.*

Поэтому это более подходящий вариант постановки запятых. **Уточнение и вставочная интонация.** Я напомню, что это значит. При вставочной интонации  фрагмент предложения выделяется паузами и произносится с общим пониженным тоном.

**А как же правило?**

Сравним: *Непременно перед тем,  **как что-то выпить, съесть или просто надкусить**, он делал торжественное лицо.*

Здесь **наречие** способствует расчленению союза. Так что всё по правилам!

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможны оба варианта. Всё зависит от логического ударения.

Основа предложения:
*Каждый раз он делал торжественное лицо.* || Вариант лучше, так как основа звучит естественнее. А придаточное вместе с союзом уточняет, когда именно "каждый раз". Ударение падает не на союз, а на "выпить".
*Каждый раз перед тЕм он делал торжественное лицо.* || Ударение падает на первую часть союза, и из-за этого она входит в главное предложение.

Ударения во всём предложении:
Каждый рАз, перед тем как что-то вЫпить, съЕсть или просто надкусИть, он делал торжественное лИцо. || Важно то, что, если союз целиком входит в придаточное, ударение падает на предыдущее слово ("раз").
Каждый раз перед тЕм, как что-то вЫпить, съЕсть или просто надкусИть, он делал торжественное лИцо.

Answer (score 1):

Как правило, союз **перед тем(,) как** расчленяется только в случае, когда придаточное предложение им присоединяется. Однако для родственного союза **в то время(,) как** условия расчленения установлены более жёсткими: даже при указанном порядке следования частей СПП расчленяемость имеет место (Лопатин, http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=536 ) *лишь при усилении временного значения, особенно при включении слов **как раз, еще, самое, именно***. На этот предмет союз **перед тем(,) как** в том же источнике не рассмотрен, но в нашем случае наблюдается сходство в отношении "усиления временного значения" первой части союза (ср. **как раз в то время, как** -> **всякий раз перед тем, как**), создающее условия для его расчленяемости. Поэтому, если только речь не идёт об учебном примере, формально опирающемся на правило (учитывать только порядок следования частей СПП), я бы выбрал такой вариант пунктуации:

> Каждый раз перед тем, как что-то выпить, съесть или просто надкусить,
>   он делал торжественное лицо.